# Passing arguments with BottomNavigationView using Safeargs component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-safe-args

I am trying to use Navigation and SafeArgs components in my Android application along with BottomNavigationView but I'm not able to pass arguments through a bottomnavigationview.

This is my case:

- HomeActivity: hosts all fragments and pass an user-id to all
  fragments

  - FragmentA: retrieve the user-id and do something..
  - FragmentB: as FragmentA
  - FragmentC: as FragmentA

In my HomeActivity I've setted up the navigation component to switch among fragments:

```
uid = "hello"
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
bottom_nav?.let {
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(it, navController)
        }
```

and passed the user-id with:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, arguments ->
    when(destination.id) {
       R.id.navigation_storyboard -> {
       val argument = NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(uid).build()
       destination.addArgument("uid", argument)
       }
    }
}
```

Inside FragmentA, I tried to get data either by using `FragmentAArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).uid` and the delegate property `by NavArg()` but I get `null` (or just default value)

Comment: have you found anything? I'm also getting null in a fragment.

Comment: Also getting null here. Any solutions guys?